# Node.JS set default program to open extension on mac

Tags: node.js, extension-methods

I have a file on my mac named `Test-encrypted_file.etfm`. But in my node.js project I have a setup file which is supposed to set `etfm` files to open with an application on my mac. How do I do that?

Comment: Sorry, what are you asking exactly? You have set a node.js app to open `etfm` files? Or you used node.js to install another app which open `etfm`?

Comment: I have an `first-time-startup` option in my node.js program, but in the first-startup I want the app to tell the operative system that `etfm` files will be opened with that program.